# Viterbi algorithm, unhardcode for general case Java

Tags: java, graph-algorithm, viterbi

my task is to find the most probable sequences of words in a sentence using viterbi algorithm.
The given sequence of states is here:
[image: all combinations]
I have to introduce initial probabilities and transition probabilities and then print the most likely sequence of parts of the speech the words of the sentence are.
The out should be smth like N P V ART, probability 0.0000123
I've hardcoded it in Java, but is there a general case or already prepared solutions in different MATH programs? thanks, here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Main
{
    //We hard-code start states and consequent observations.
        static final String NOUN = "Noun";
        static final String ARTICLE = "Article";

        static final String VERB = "Verb";
        static final String ADJECTIVE = "Adjective";
        static final String ADVERB = "Adverb";

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
//We put them in array
                String[] states = new String[] {NOUN, ARTICLE};

                String[] observations = new String[] {VERB, ADJECTIVE, ADVERB};

        //Define a hashtable where we’ll keep initial states and their probabilities
                Hashtable<String, Float> start_probability = new Hashtable<String, Float>();
                start_probability.put(NOUN, 0.6f);
                start_probability.put(ARTICLE, 0.4f);

                // A hashtable with transition_probabilities which contains initial probablilities
                Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Float>> transition_probability =
                        new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Float>>();
                        Hashtable<String, Float> t1 = new Hashtable<String, Float>();
                        t1.put(NOUN, 0.7f);
                        t1.put(ARTICLE, 0.3f);
                        Hashtable<String, Float> t2 = new Hashtable<String, Float>();
                        t2.put(NOUN, 0.4f);
                        t2.put(ARTICLE, 0.6f);
                transition_probability.put(NOUN, t1);
                transition_probability.put(ARTICLE, t2);


                //  Here we put  hashtables with consequent observed emission_probability
                Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Float>> emission_probability =
                        new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Float>>();
                        Hashtable<String, Float> e1 = new Hashtable<String, Float>();
                        e1.put(VERB, 0.1f);
                        e1.put(ADJECTIVE, 0.4f);
                        e1.put(ADVERB, 0.5f);
                        Hashtable<String, Float> e2 = new Hashtable<String, Float>();
                        e2.put(VERB, 0.6f);
                        e2.put(ADJECTIVE, 0.3f);
                        e2.put(ADVERB, 0.1f);
                emission_probability.put(NOUN, e1);
                emission_probability.put(ARTICLE, e2);

    //We return the most probabilistic sequence with function forward fiterb described below
                Object[] ret = forward_viterbi(observations,
                           states,
                           start_probability,
                           transition_probability,
                           emission_probability);
                System.out.println(((Float) ret[0]).floatValue());
                System.out.println((String) ret[1]);
                System.out.println(((Float) ret[2]).floatValue());
        }
//Function to go
//As argument we get nested hashtables
        public static Object[] forward_viterbi(String[] obs, String[] states,
                        Hashtable<String, Float> start_p,
                        Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Float>> trans_p,
                        Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Float>> emit_p)
        {
                Hashtable<String, Object[]> T = new Hashtable<String, Object[]>();
                for (String state : states)
                        T.put(state, new Object[] {start_p.get(state), state, start_p.get(state)});

                for (String output : obs)
                {
                        Hashtable<String, Object[]> U = new Hashtable<String, Object[]>();
                        for (String next_state : states)
                        {
                                float total = 0;
                                String argmax = "";
                                float valmax = 0;

                                float prob = 1;
                                String v_path = "";
                                float v_prob = 1;

                                for (String source_state : states)
                                {
                                        Object[] objs = T.get(source_state);
                                        prob = ((Float) objs[0]).floatValue();
                                        v_path = (String) objs[1];
                                        v_prob = ((Float) objs[2]).floatValue();

                                        float p = emit_p.get(source_state).get(output) *
                                                          trans_p.get(source_state).get(next_state);
                                        prob *= p;
                                        v_prob *= p;
                                        total += prob;
                                        if (v_prob > valmax)
                                        {
                                                argmax = v_path + "," + next_state;
                                                valmax = v_prob;
                                        }
                                }
                                U.put(next_state, new Object[] {total, argmax, valmax});
                        }
                        T = U;
                }

                float total = 0;
                String argmax = "";
                float valmax = 0;

                float prob;
                String v_path;
                float v_prob;

                for (String state : states)
                {
                        Object[] objs = T.get(state);
                        prob = ((Float) objs[0]).floatValue();
                        v_path = (String) objs[1];
                        v_prob = ((Float) objs[2]).floatValue();
                        total += prob;
                        if (v_prob > valmax)
                        {
                                argmax = v_path;
                                valmax = v_prob;
                        }
                }
                return new Object[]{
                        total, argmax, valmax


                        };
                }
}
```